# Stop javascript function if not finished within 5 seconds (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I currently use several APIs to pull data from other sites. However, sometimes the APIs are incredibly slow (especially Twitter) and the script will continue to run perpetually because Twitter never responds.

My question is how can I tell the function to stop IF and ONLY IF it hasn't completed in x number of seconds? I'm assuming this has something to do with setTimeout(), but I can't figure it out.

Here's some example code from the Yahoo Weather API:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $.simpleWeather({
            zipcode: '<?= $property_zip ?>',
            unit: 'f',
            success: function(weather) {
                //success
            },
            error: function(error) {
                $("#weathercontent").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Are you getting JSONP of tweets? You can use the timeout in jQuery.

Comment: Long running functions will be shut down by browsers anyway. So I wonder how you've done it. Can you please provide some code (only the relevant parts please) so we can see how we can help.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik i put some code up.. let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a global timeout for all jQuery AJAX requests to 5 seconds. I believe this also covers JSONP requests since jQuery 1.5, but it may be worth investigating.

You could setup a single handler where timeout is set. It could be based on the URL of the outgoing request. So maybe for all calls to Yahoo, or Flickr, or Twitter, you can set a timeout. The pre-filter below would run before each AJAX request is sent, and gets a chance to modify the request fully before it is sent.

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
    if (options.url is not going to my server) { // pseudocode :)
        options.timeout = 5000;
    }
});
```

If you don't want a global handler, then set the `timeout` property in each `$.ajax({ .. })` call you are making. This could be problematic for 3rd-party plugins such as `simpleWeather` which you'll have to modify the source for if setting the timeout explicitly.

Comment: can I do this for only a select few functions?

Comment: @user - yes you can do it selectively. I am adding an example for that.

Comment: @user628596: Just FYI: The easiest way is to set timeout on `$.ajax` options, but if you find this limiting, you can still use other means like setting up your own timers (that works as you desire) and use `.abort()` function on the XHR request object. Just so you know there are other means as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how can you cancel the ajax request if the server response is slow?  I believe it's myAjaxRequest.abort(). This is not that same thing as stopping a function mid-execution. I'm not sure there's a way to do that.